# r studio фильтрация

Tags: r

как в R отфильтровать строки по значению в списке? Например, у меня есть список из строк (а,б,с,д). Есть dataframe со столбцом name, в котором встречаются значения (а,б,с,д,е,р,п,н,м). Мне нужно оставить только те строки, где значение столбца name равно значению из списка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и покажите как пытались, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Или воспользуйтесь поиском - эта тема неоднократно обсуждалась ранее.

Answer (score 1):

dataframe=subset(dataframe,names %in% unique(unlist(your_names_list))) # если имена хранятся в списке;

dataframe=subset(dataframe,names %in% unique(your_names_list)) # если имена в векторе.